# Drawing a series of lines doesn't obey lineJoin='rounded'

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a drawing application. I track drawing on the canvas and then render it using something like so:

```
canvas.moveTo(x[0]-1, y[0]);
for(var i=0;i<x.length;i++)
{
  canvas.lineTo(x[i], y[i]);
  canvas.moveTo(x[i], y[i]);
}
```

In this way, a "stroke" of the mouse, results in a series of lines being drawn in order of where you visit the canvas with your mouse.

However, this doesn't render right. It looks choppy and definitely not "round" as I have the lineJoin set to. I can solve this by instead creating a closing, stroking, and creating a new path at each `moveTo` in the loop. This is horribly slow however.

Why do my lines end up drawing in a very blocky and weird manner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because each line "continues" at the moveTo, the lines are never really "joined". It is all just considered one big line. The solution to making this render smoothly is to set the `lineCap` property of the canvas context to "round".

This still isn't quite the same though for some reason and some "choppiness" around corners is seen, but is not extremely obvious as before